# $http not working in iOS 8.2 in Ionic / AngularJS app

Tags: php, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

The following code works in my Ionic app for iOS version 9.3++  but NOT for iOS 8.2:

```
  $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://example.com',
      data: {username: username, password: password }
  }).then(function(result) {
     //I wish!
  },function(error) {
    //unfortunately we end up here for iOS 8.2, but not for 9.3 or greater
  });
```

I have verified that both versions get the POST data to the server and the server generates the proper response.

iOS 8.3 throws the error:

```
Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost.
```

I suspect some kind of browser settings / permissions / CORS issue but have not found a solution on SO or google.

My server (PHP) is setup to receive ajax requests like this:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
   header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
}

//Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
   if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'])) {      
       header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
   }
   if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS'])) {
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        
      {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
   } 
   exit(0); 
}

//processing code goes here and a proper $response is created
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Try setting the content type in the header. e.g. `Content-Type: application/json`.. I had a similar error before and that was the problem after hours of debugging.. hope that helps!

Comment: It is set as: `Content-Type application/json;charset=UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

try to add this line in your http request

headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

Comment: That breaks the server (400 error), which is expecting JSON. Again, the code works perfectly on iOS 9,10, and android, and browser.

Comment: can you me your cordova version

Comment: remove cordova-plugin-whitelist and add back the whitelist and add <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" /> to your config.xml

Comment: Cordova v6.4.  I uninstalled and reinstalled the whitelist plugin and added that line to config.xml. I already had `href="*"`.  Didn't work.